# PyGame.error in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

I have problem with pygame and python 3 in ubuntu 12.10. When i tried load an image i got this error:

> pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file

But in python 2.7 all works fine.
I use code from http://inventwithpython.com/chapter19.html

Sorry for my poor English.

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
# set up pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
# set up the window
WINDOWWIDTH = 400
WINDOWHEIGHT = 400
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Sprites and Sound')
# set up the colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
# set up the block data structure
player = pygame.Rect(300, 100, 40, 40)
playerImage = pygame.image.load('player.png')
playerStretchedImage = pygame.transform.scale(playerImage, (40, 40))
foodImage = pygame.image.load('cherry.png')
foods = []
for i in range(20):
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 20, 20))
foodCounter = 0
NEWFOOD = 40
# set up keyboard variables
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False
MOVESPEED = 6
# set up music
pickUpSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('pickup.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('background.mid')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
musicPlaying = True
# run the game loop
while True:
    # check for the QUIT event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            # change the keyboard variables
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == ord('x'):
                player.top = random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - player.height)
                player.left = random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - player.width)
            if event.key == ord('m'):
                if musicPlaying:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                else:
                    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
                musicPlaying = not musicPlaying
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(event.pos[0] - 10, event.pos[1] - 10, 20, 20))
    foodCounter += 1
    if foodCounter >= NEWFOOD:
        # add new food
        foodCounter = 0
        foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 20, 20))
    # draw the black background onto the surface
    windowSurface.fill(BLACK)
    # move the player
    if moveDown and player.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
        player.top += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and player.top > 0:
        player.top -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and player.left > 0:
        player.left -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and player.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
        player.right += MOVESPEED
    # draw the block onto the surface
    windowSurface.blit(playerStretchedImage, player)
    # check if the block has intersected with any food squares.
    for food in foods[:]:
        if player.colliderect(food):
            foods.remove(food)
            player = pygame.Rect(player.left, player.top, player.width + 2, player.height + 2)
            playerStretchedImage = pygame.transform.scale(playerImage, (player.width, player.height))
            if musicPlaying:
                pickUpSound.play()
    # draw the food
    for food in foods:
        windowSurface.blit(foodImage, food)
    # draw the window onto the screen
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)
```

Comment: I reposted the comment as an answer so that you can close out this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu released repo specifically shows Python 2.7 as a dependency of PyGame 1.6.1 which is the current version in the Ubuntu Released repo. It may just be the only version of Python supported by the package.

To see this info yourself try `apt-cache depends python-pygame`.