# full built file support PYGAME

Tags: python, image, ubuntu, pygame

I cant load images thats not BMP files in pygame.
Ive searched everywhere for solution but I couldn't find one.
In pygame site they say this:

> The image module is a required dependency of Pygame, but it only
>   optionally supports any extended file formats. By default it can only
>   load uncompressed BMP images. When built with full image support, the
>   pygame.image.load - load new image from a file function can support
>   the following formats.

I couldn't understand what to do, and how can I get the full build image support.

I am running python 3.3 on ubuntu 13.04.
I'm new to python.

help?

the error:

```
File "/home2/tor/workspace/PYGAME/src/Main.py", line 13, in <module>
ball = pygame.image.load("/home2/tor/Downloads/ball.gif")
pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file
```

BTW I also tried this on jpg file.

Comment: How did you install pygame?

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Pygame may not be sufficient for Python 3 on your system, I believe ubuntu 13.04 comes with Python 3 installed by default, I am not sure if it has Python 2, but if it did happen to have it, I would use that instead.

Information from this question: [PyGame.error in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444705/pygame-error-in-ubuntu)

Right below where it says "can support the following formats" the list says:

```
JPG
PNG
GIF (non animated)
BMP
PCX
TGA (uncompressed)
TIF
LBM (and PBM)
PBM (and PGM, PPM)
XPM
```

Although it does say it is not a Windows BMP file, that does not mean it has to be bmp. I do not believe `gif` is supported when animated as the list says.

Here is an example from the pygame comments for a `png` image.

`char_surf=pygame.image.load(os.path.join('data', 'char.png'))`

Comment: the gif is not animated.